# Setting up reverse proxy using Apache on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am trying to setup Reverse Proxy using Apache Server 2.4.23 for two different domain. One domain is pointing to localhost site and other is pointing to other server web site. Here are my configuration

```
Listen 111.111.11.222:80
Listen 111.111.11.333:80
<VirtualHost 111.111.11.222:80>
ServerName myapp.com

ErrorLog "logs/app_error_log"
CustomLog "logs/app_access_log" common

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / http://111.111.11.222:8090/
ProxyPassReverse / http://111.111.11.222:8090/
<Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 111.111.11.333:80>
ServerName myauditor.com
ProxyRequests Off
# ProxyPreserveHost On

ErrorLog "logs/auditor_error_log"
CustomLog "logs/auditor_access_log" common

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / http://www.mycompamy.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.mycompany.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

In these settings, first "myapp.com" is working fine as needed. However when I try myauditor.com then instead of acting it as reverse proxy, it is redirecting to www.mycompany.com.
In myauditor.com setting, if I un-comment and use **ProxyPreserveHost On** then myauditor.com start giving me error

> Invalid URL
>   The requested URL "http://%5bNo%20Host%5d/", is invalid.
>   Reference #9.2d3d6b68.1485193636.126886bd

I am new to Apache so I am not sure, when ProxyPreserveHost is working fine in first VirtualHost then why it causing issue in second VirtualHost.

Comment: What is ProxyPass / http://www.google.com/ for?  You are piping requests to google?

Comment: @Adrien its just an example to explain settings. I am using my own web sites for piping request. Updated thread for clearing this confusion.